# Problemas con la función mutate()

Tags: r

primero que todo, me disculpo por las probables imprecisiones terminológicas que pueda tener mi pregunta, pues no tengo formación en el campo de la programación. Estoy intentando hacer gráficos con R para la parte descriptiva de mi investigación de doctorado sobre orden de palabras en español. Básicamente lo que quiero hacer es un gráfico de barras con dos variables categóricas, una dependiente y otra independiente, que muestre las barras ordenadas de mayor a menor en función de la cantidad de casos (n) que tenga cada categoría. En el caso del gráfico de una de las variables independientes (semántica verbal), he implementado los siguientes códigos

```
#dataframe

df <- data %>% count(Semántica.verbal, Orden.del.sujeto) %>% mutate(frecr=n/sum(n)) #es el siguiente, donde data es una base de datos mayor
```

```
 df
   Semántica.verbal Orden.del.sujeto   n       frecr
1       existencial               SV  22 0.031428571
2       existencial               VS  65 0.092857143
3          material               SV  38 0.054285714
4          material               VS  57 0.081428571
5            mental               SV  49 0.070000000
6            mental               VS  65 0.092857143
7        modulacion               SV   9 0.012857143
8        modulacion               VS   3 0.004285714
9        relacional               SV 146 0.208571429
10       relacional               VS 224 0.320000000
11           verbal               SV  10 0.014285714
12           verbal               VS  12 0.017142857
>
```

El problema viene cuando intento ordenar la variable. Al usar el siguiente código:

```
orden_df <- df %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate(Semántica.verbal = factor(Semántica.verbal, level= Semántica.verbal))
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Semántica.verbal`.
> x factor level [2] is duplicated
> ℹ Input `Semántica.verbal` is `factor(Semántica.verbal, level = Semántica.verbal)`.

He buscado información en internet pero no logro descifrar qué está pasando... ¿alguien me podría ayudar?

De antemano, gracias!

## Actualización

Agradecida por la solución brindada, ha funcionado perfectamente para la función `unique()`. Sin embargo, cuando intento ordenar usando `fct_reorder()`, función que me parece más práctica, no me funciona. El código para ordenar, según la sugerencia que me han dado, es el siguiente:

```
orden_df_1 <-  df %>% mutate(Semántica.verbal = fct_reorder(Semántica.verbal, desc(n)))
```

El dataframe queda de la siguiente manera:

```
orden_df_1
   Semántica.verbal Orden.del.sujeto   n       frecr
1       existencial               SV  22 0.031428571
2       existencial               VS  65 0.092857143
3          material               SV  38 0.054285714
4          material               VS  57 0.081428571
5            mental               SV  49 0.070000000
6            mental               VS  65 0.092857143
7        modulacion               SV   9 0.012857143
8        modulacion               VS   3 0.004285714
9        relacional               SV 146 0.208571429
10       relacional               VS 224 0.320000000
11           verbal               SV  10 0.014285714
12           verbal               VS  12 0.017142857
```

O sea, que sigue ordenado por orden alfabético para los niveles de las dos variables que quiero representar...

Por otra parte, intenté generar el plot usando directamente la función fct_reorder() dentro de ggplot(). El código es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(orden_df_1, aes(x = fct_reorder(Semántica.verbal, desc(n)), y = n, fill= Orden.del.sujeto))+ 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack")
```

A continuación les muestro el gráfico:

[image: Gráfico de barras]

Y efectivamente me sale el gráfico ordenado, pero por el nivel SV que es el que menos n tiene en todos los casos, pues supongo que ha respetado el orden alfabético. ¿Pueden iluminarme sobre cómo solucionar ambos problemas?

Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Bienvenida/o Dania. Creo que la pregunta está ejemplarmente formulada: señala claramente el resultado esperado, muestra el código con el que lo intentaste resolver y tiene datos de ejemplo para reproducir el error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectivamente no estoy familiarizada con el funcionamiento de la página. Intenté poner la pregunta como comentario a la respuesta que me habían dado pero no me dejaba copiar bien el código y el data frame. Haré las modificaciones necesarias. Saludos!

Comment: Respondiendo a tu actualización: por defecto `fct_reorder()` reordena por la mediana de la variable numérica (en este caso `n`) agrupada por el factor (en este caso `Semántica.verbal`). En tu gráfico queda ordenado por altura de barras total: SV+VS. La variable `Orden.del.sujeto` no incide en el reordenado, aunque se usa en el gráfico al estar especificada en `fill = `. De todos modos actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias nuevamente!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que obtienes estrictamente no lo produce `mutate`, sino la función `factor` que usas dentro del `mutate`. Sin embargo como a esa función la llama `mutate` el error sale por ahí. ¿A qué se debe el error? En el argumento `levels` estás pasando todo el vector `Semántica.verbal`, que tiene elementos repetidos. Por `help(factor)`

```
levels  an optional vector of the **unique** values (as character strings) that x might have taken.
```

Es decir, no debería haber elementos repetidos ahí. Una solución simple:

```
orden_df <- df %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
  mutate(Semántica.verbal = factor(Semántica.verbal, 
                                   level= unique(Semántica.verbal)))
```

Al usar `unique()` se eliminan las repeticiones y se cumple con el requisito de no tener niveles repetidos en el factor. Además se conserva el orden que le diste con `arrange`, que es lo que te interesa para el gráfico que vas a hacer.

Alternativamente puedes usar la función `fct_reorder`, de la librería `forcats` que también está en `tidyverse`. En ese caso:

```
df %>% mutate(Semántica.verbal = fct_reorder(Semántica.verbal, desc(n)))
```

`fct_reorder` toma dos argumentos obligatorios, el primero es el factor cuyos niveles queremos reordenar y el segundo una variable numérica que vamos a usar como criterio para el orden.  No es necesario el `arrange` previo y de hecho podrías usarla directamente en la llamada de de `ggplot`. Algo así como

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = fct_reorder(Semántica.verbal, desc(n), y = n))
```

## Orden arbitrario de las columnas

Si el orden que te da `fct_reorder` no es el que buscas puedes reordenar al factor que controla el orden de las columnas "manualmente" y darle el orden que prefieras. Es tan simple como definir un vector de caracteres con los niveles en el orden que prefieres y luego pasar ese vector como argumento de `levels =`  en `factor`.

```
niveles <- c("relacional", "existencial", "mental", "material", "verbal","modulacion") 

df %>% 
  mutate(Semántica.verbal = factor(Semántica.verbal, 
                                   levels = niveles)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Semántica.verbal, 
            y = n, 
            fill= Orden.del.sujeto)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", 
           position="stack")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias! funcionó perfectamente... sumamente agradecida!